# how can I modify the validation of a field using formBuilder in real time

Tags: angular

I am using the `formBuilder` to build the validations of my forms. but I would like to modify the rules of one of them (`cellphone` field). I have something like this:

```
this.register= this.formBuilder.group({
 cellphone:[
  null,
  Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])
 ]
})
```

and I would like to modify, for example, that the validation of the `cellphone` field `maxlenght` is 5.

how can I update this rule in real time?

```
function updateRulerCellphone(){ 
  //modify rule
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setValidators()`, to dynamically add `Validators` to form control

```
this.register.controls["cellphone"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]);
this.register.controls["cellphone"].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Friend I have problems with your code:  look please.. https://i.imgur.com/Ts2giCW.jpg

Comment: You need to import it as `import { Validators } from "@angular/forms";`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance! You're right, I wanted to ask you one last question, how can I see the error in the view? for example, I want you to tell me dynamically the value of the maxlenght required. for example : <div *ngIf="..">maxlength: {{}}>

Comment: You can use `hasError` for that. `{{this.register.get("cellphone").hasError('maxlength')}};`

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I want to show the characters that I defined in the rule.